# Show that $4ℤ/12ℤ ≃ ℤ_3$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying to understand how $4ℤ/12ℤ$ is isomorphic to $ℤ_3$.
So far I understand that:
$$4ℤ/12ℤ = \{ 0+12ℤ,4+12ℤ,8+12ℤ \}$$
and that elements of integer $\bmod 3$ are:
$$ℤ_3 =\{ 0,1,2\}$$
However, I cannot figure out how $4ℤ/12ℤ$ is isomorphic to $ℤ_3$. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: General framework for _most_ "show that two groups are isomorphic" exercises: Step 1: Pick a function that looks like it might be an isomorphism. Step 2: Show that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @ParasGupta Did you just copy the text of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807616) question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to solving your problem would be by constructing an isomorphism between the two groups. For example consider:
$$
\varphi: 4\mathbb{Z} /12\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}
$$
$$
0+12z \mapsto 0+12z \mod 3, \qquad 4+12z \mapsto 4+12z \mod 3, \qquad 8+12z \mapsto 8+12z \mod 3
$$
(So really $[0] \mapsto [0]$, $[4] \mapsto [1]$ and $[8] \mapsto [2]$)

One would now only have to prove that this is indeed an group homomorphism ($\varphi(a+b) = \varphi(a) + \varphi(b)$) and especially isomorphic.

Also one would have to prove the independence of the homomorphism of the variable $z$, which is somewhat obvious since $12z \equiv 0 \mod 3$ for all $z$.